How to get all HTML tags from a page content using BeautifulSoup?
I'm trying to retrieve a tag text from a HTML page but I notice that BeautifulSoup is not "reading" all HTML elements, e.g:
This is the part that I'm working on, the full page have a lot of elements:
<div class="TableContainer">
    <div class="CaptionContainer">
        <div class="CaptionInnerContainer">
            <span class="CaptionEdgeLeftTop"></span>
            <span class="CaptionEdgeRightTop"></span>
            <span class="CaptionBorderTop"></span>
            <span class="CaptionVerticalLeft"></span>
            <div class="Text">Character Information</div> <span class="CaptionVerticalRight"></span>
            <span class="CaptionBorderBottom"></span>
            <span class="CaptionEdgeLeftBottom"></span>
            <span class="CaptionEdgeRightBottom"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

When I try to find the "Text" class from CaptionInnerContainer the CaptionInnerContainer is empty.
import httpx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

CHARACTER_URL = "https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name={name}"
character_name = "Aliance Bombao"

async def _get(url: str):
    """
    Retrieve the page HTML content the for given URL
    """
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        return await client.get(url)


async def get_character(name: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    response = await _get(CHARACTER_URL.format(name=name))
    response.raise_for_status()

    return BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")


page = await get_character(character_name)
tables = page.find_all("div", class_="TableContainer")

caption = tables[0].find("div", class_="CaptionContainer")
inner = caption.find("div", class_="CaptionInnerContainer")

text = inner.find("div", class_="Text").text

print(text)  ## None

How can I ensure that BeautifulSoup is reading all HTML elements? When I try to debug it using ipython I can see that the CaptionInnerContainer has only one child element (CaptionEdgeLeftTop)

can you share the complete code to recreate this issue? as it's giving 403 Forbidden. And this dom is not dynamically loading, So there shouldn't be any issues like not loading the elements properly

html.parser seems to have some issues parsing <br> tags, but lxml works perfectly.
I suggest installing the lxml parser using pip install lxml.
Using .select() and .select_one() we can directly target elements using css selectors just like in the browser.
Using this selector: div.BoxContent > div.TableContainer we can select all the table containers excluding the Search Character table, and the hidden tables (cookies).
We can then create a dict mapping each table caption to  its <table> element.

Code:
Note: in this code I used requests but it can easily be converted to use httpx
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

character_url = 'https://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name={name}'
character_name = 'Aliance Bombao'

url = character_url.format(name=character_name)

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml') # don't forget to install lxml

# html.parser has issues with this selector
containers = soup.select('div.BoxContent > div.TableContainer') # select all relevant containers

# maps each caption(string) to its <table>(element)
# {'Character Information': <table> ... </table>, }
tables = {c.select_one('div.Text').text: c.select_one('table.TableContent') for c in containers}

